# portable hand scanner works with ipad (for eldery person)

Tags: scanner

I want to help an eldery man (>70) who wants to send scans of his incoming mail to his son.

I'm thinking of an hand scanner (something like: https://www.amazon.de/Easypix-Easy-scan-A4-Scanner-schwarz/dp/B0038JQIF6). A desktop scanner is not an option, due to space limitations, and limited mobility of the man.

Main criteria:

- Cable less, (Bluetooth)
- Direct interaction with IPad via Bluetooth. There should be an app where the man can online see the result of the scan.
- Simple GUI of app. Main features requried are: Scan Document. Safe to file. Send by email. More complex options  (like dpi, OCR, post processing) are not required, and should not result in some complex GUI.
- Not too small displays or bottons on the device. shall be useable also if the eyesight is not perfect anymore.

Not so important:

- Scan quality (dpi)
- OCR

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the [Dacuda Pocketscan](http://dacuda.com/pocketscan/) which as previously a successful Kickstarter project.

It fits most of your requirements. Most, because being a hand-sized item, the power button is on the small side, about Pez candy size. The begin/end scan button is the larger round button on the top. Results are good, although most of my scans with it are newspaper quality and picks up the dark on the flip side of the paper. It's not the scanner that's poor quality, it's the paper.
[image]

This is the result of a scan of a day-to-day single page calendar, with better quality paper.

When the scanner is powered up, if the i-Device is turned on and the app installed, it takes the signal and asks permission to start, reducing the need to find the app on the device. Once permitted, pressing the button on the scan device begins the scan.

It does require reasonably steady hands and the ability to recognize overlap areas which are used to register previous passes of the scanner.

The age of the user and tiny button may disqualify this item.

What is objectionable with the item you linked as an example?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed. Explanation. Sounds like a realy intresting option.     The item i have linked has the following limitations: usb cable based no bluetooth.  Therefore needs to be plugged to a pc. Handlin scanner cable plus laptop at once might be anoying also for fitter persons. I don't expect that i can directly plug it to an i-pad. First scanning and then Transfer data to a pc are worksteps which add complexity. (transfering the small memory card is also no option)  therefore i realy like your option, where you directly see what is scanned, w/o annoying cables.

Comment: I thought at first that it was going to be rarely used, but the convenience factor of nearly-instant scanning with auto-transfer via bluetooth certainly improved my perspective. The images also have the typical i-Device menu feature for sending by email, text message or dropbox among others.